# How to hyperlink webpages through a flash file

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, tomcat, macromedia

Hello everyone i am developing web application in net beans 7.0.1 and using MySQL as database and Apache tomcat as server. I am developing an jsp web pages. **i have developed a flash file  .swf file as my home page which i included in my jsp file.** my .**swf file is an movie clip. i have added some menus in that i want to link that menus to appropriate jsp  files of my application.** how can i do that? Please help me. I am a student doing final year project and don't have much knowledge about flash files . for editing flash files i am using Macromedia flash player 8.0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActionScript 2, use

```
getURL("urltoload", "target");
```

If you are using AS3, use

```
var url:String = "http://site";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
navigateToURL(request, 'target');
```

Where target can be _self, _blank, _top, etc.

Comment: when editing flash files it shows me actionscripts 1.0 and 2.0. will you please explain me what is target in that geturl metchod?

Comment: and which event handler is available in flash so that i can redirect it my web pages after clicking on menus

Comment: Depends on how you are creating the menus, most of them would have onclick event. Target is the target window where yo want to open the link, example _self will open in same window, _blank in new window, _top is required if you have frames in your DOM (most likely not, so ignore).